# Assigning a Variable and a Column to a Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm converting stored procedures from SQL Server to MySQL and I've encountered a query that has me stumped:

```
UPDATE T_Example 
SET @ExampleVar = ExampleColumn = 0 
WHERE ExampleColumn2 = @ExampleVar2;
```

For security purposes, I have altered the names of variables but the syntax is the same.

I have never seen this type of transitive assignment, and I'm confused as to the behavior.

Is it setting

```
@ExampleVar = 0 AND setting ExampleColumn = 0
```

or is it setting

```
@ExampleVar = ExampleColumn, THEN setting ExampleColumn = 0
```

If it's the former, then I assume the easiest solution is to check the `ROW_COUNT()` after the `UPDATE` and if it's `> 0` then I assign the variable to `0` within an `IF` block. (Not pretty, but I think that's the most elegant solution.)

If it's the latter, then I'm not exactly sure how to approach it, so suggestions there would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) is rather clear on what the assignment means:

> `SET @variable = column = expression` sets the variable to the same
>   value as the column. This differs from `SET @variable = column, column
>   = expression`, which sets the variable to the pre-update value of the column.

So, the equivalent MySQL statement is

```
UPDATE T_Example
    SET ExampleColumn = (@ExampleVar := 0)
    WHERE ExampleColumn2 = @ExampleVar2;
```

Note the use of `:=` in the statement.

Comment: While your query does technically work, I've noticed that it doesn't work inside a stored procedure. I can't figure out why this is the case, but if I replicate the exact same query inside of a stored procedure it does not work. Outside of the procedure, it functions just fine.

Comment: @B.Roth . . . Perhaps you should ask another question.  There is no reasonobvious  this would not work in a stored procedure..

Comment: I figured it out, the difference was with the @ExampleVar variable. In the stored procedure, I wasn't using it as a session variable, but instead as a procedure variable. Apparently, procedure variables will not work for this type of query, but session variables will.